# Is it possible to save NSData(obtained from NSKeyedArchiver) as NSString and then read back as NSData?

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

I want to save some information to video metadata. Now I can save the text, that is `String` object.

```
// this works well
let metaItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
metaItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeySource as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
metaItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon
metaItem.value = String("some text") as! NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
```

So instead of just `String` I'd like to serialize custom object:

```
class ARTRMetadata: NSObject, NSCoding {
   // ... 
   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //...
   }
   func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        //...
   }
}
```

I tried to convert `Data` to `String`, it crashed, now I stucked at writing/reading that `Data` to `.txt` file:

```
static func saveMetadataObjectAsText(memento: ARTRMetadata)->String {
        let tempFilepath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("someFile2.txt")
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: tempFilepath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

        if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(memento, toFile: tempFilepath) {}
        else { print("archiveRootObject toFile: FAILURE") }

        do {
           let contentsFeedToMetadataItem = try String(contentsOfFile: tempFilepath)
           //let contentsFeedToMetadataItem = try String(contentsOfFile: tempFilepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) // The file “someFile2.txt” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8).
           return contentsFeedToMetadataItem
        }
        catch { print(error) }
        return "ERROR in contentsFeedToMetadataItem"
    }
```

Now it crashes because "The file “someFile2.txt” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined."

I suppose the problem is that `NSData` obtained from `NSKeyedArchiver` is not valid `NSString`. If I am correct, how to dump the data as text? And then restore it with the same bytes (for `NSKeyedUnarchiver`)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to save data as text file? Even if you could save `Data` as string (indeed you can if you encode it with base64) it's not human readable anyway – well there might be a very few people who can read base64 fluently.

Long story short, save `Data` directly to disk and read it back. `Data` provides appropriate API.

By the way: `archiveRootObject(toFile` writes `Data` anyway, so read `try Data(contentsOfFile: tempFilepath)` and return that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check it in action on Monday, and then 'll accept. :)